# WiFi P2P Communication(Already Connected Devices)

Tags: java, android, wifip2p

I try to make an app that send a message(String) to another app, I follow the official documentation : `https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p` but was too overwhelming because I'm a beginner.I found later a tutorial based on the official documentation but app doesn't work properly, the app crashed.Anyway , I don't want to carry the whole process for making a P2P connection, I just want to send that message for already connected device(manually) , I'm trying something like that but I don't know how:

`If CONNECTED_DEVICES is equal to 1
    sendMessage("Ana Are Mere");
Else If CONNECTED DEVICES is greater that 1 
    Toast : "Connect With Only A Device"
Else 
    Toast : "No Devices Connected"`

It's not a very beautiful example, but that's my idea.